# Google Recaptcha (PHP)

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

So, it seems quite simple, I have added a Google recaptcha to my [website](http://filthysloth.com/Upload.html) with the following to HTML codes.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My key would be here"></div>
```

However, people can still fill the form and send mail without completing the captcha. (So they do not have to solve any puzzles they can just get straight through which is leaving me vunerable to bots of course)

So, I basically need PHP code that checks to see if the users has actually "Ticked" or "Completed" the Recaptcha. So then they can proceed to send mail.

My PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($email != '') {
            if ($human == '4') {                 
                if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
                    echo '<p>You have successfully submitted your information to PS4RS. Subscribers to our mailing list will begin to periodically receive updates.</p>';
                } else { 
                    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p><p><input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" class="goback" /></p>'; 
                } 
            } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != '4') {
                echo '<p>You answered the anti-spam question incorrectly!</p><p><input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" class="goback" /></p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<p>You need to fill in all required fields!!</p><p><input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" class="goback" /></p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

I really have no clue in how to code in PHP, this is my best attempt.

Comment: You haven't implemented anything [within the server-side validation from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php#quick-start). Give that a go first.

Comment: @brimstone No. That's just his PHP for the existing form, nothing to do with Google Recaptcha there.

Comment: If you [Google it](https://www.google.no/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=active&q=google+recaptcha+example) you'll find examples of how you'll need to implement the Google reCAPTCHA to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not my original answer, I found it [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/please-help-me-implement-google-recaptcha-server-side/205823)

> ```
> <?php
>   $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $yoursecret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
>   $googleobj = json_decode($response);
>   $verified = $googleobj->success;
>   if ($verified === true){
>     //do stuff
>   }
> ```

so for your purpose...

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']) {
  $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=". $yoursecret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  $googleobj = json_decode($response);
  $verified = $googleobj->success;
  if($verified === true) {
    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
      echo '<p>You have successfully submitted your information to PS4RS. Subscribers to our mailing list will begin to periodically receive updates.</p>';
    } else { 
      echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p><p><input type="button" value="Go Back" onclick="history.back(-1)" class="goback" /></p>'; 
    } 
  }
}
?>
```

Be sure to add your **SECRET KEY** in for `$yoursecret`

(That's different from the site key)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official Google dev webpage:

```
<?php
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "your_private_key";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
        die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    } else {
        // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    }
?>
```

Tell me if this helps

Comment: the recaptcha php api has depreciated